# Changing http to https in wordpress website, activate ssl certificate

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https, migration

Hey i have activated a ssl certifcicate and all routes stopped working. I repaired every url/address in database and mass replaced all http:// with https:// in ftp files, also manually searched for http occurences in code but found nothing. I did many tutorials, searched many websites but solution seems to be more complicated. If anybody deal with problem like mine in the past please tell me how to solve it.

It remains to repair css and js assets:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://wiadomosci.nowakonstytucja.org/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://wiadomosci.nowakonstytucja.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://wiadomosci.nowakonstytucja.org/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://wiadomosci.nowakonstytucja.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Try install "Really Simple SSL" plugin. It's should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the file by the entire URL " 'http://wiadomosci.nowakonstytucja.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.8'"

If the file is local, then ref it by  "/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.8'" , and you will avoid the whole http situation altogether.

Google does this with some of their files that haven't been upgraded yet.